# Mistake on the email reply?

Tags: interviewing, email

I'm worried that mistake I'd committed on my reply to an email might be taken wrongly:

His reply -  *Please assured be that we will update when we have the orders*.

My reply -   *Please be assured- I'll get the work done.*

My q- whether my mistake is grave ?

Comment: I don't see a *grammatical* mistake here. Your reply is a perfectly formed sentence.

Comment: Based on your writing, I am fairly certain that you are not a native speaker of English. You resume/CV should be error-free but there is significant latitude for minor errors and grammatical awkwardness in other communication with HR or the hiring-manager if they're aware that you are not a native speaker and if the job isn't focused entirely on communication.

Comment: Why did you substitute "approvals" for "orders" in your reply?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English usage, not navigating the workplace. Consider asking a similar question on English Language Learners instead.

Comment: @hello, I don't think using "assured" is technically wrong. But the response (and even the question) as a whole sounds a little awkward to a _native_ English speaker. I think it is probably OK and not even close to a "grave error". Don't worry.

Comment: @teego1967 - this native English speaker doesn't find it awkward - merely formal, and there's nothing wrong with that

Comment: @teego1967 & HorusKol  - Thanks much. It's a great learning for me. I'll avoid being fancy and keep my written communication simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response reads to me like a simple formal restatement of what they wrote to you. They asked you to be assured for reasons, you responded that you are assured for those reasons.

There is no grammatical error, and it is most definitely not worth sweating over. Most certainly do not follow up with an email saying "Hi, I think I made a mistake in my last email" - because you didn't, and that will fully confuse the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on:-

1. The position you applied for (job profile) i.e. Manager, Sr. Manager, Trainee, Technical, Development etc.
2. Number and quality of other candidates who applied for the job
3. Behavior, strictness and mood of the HR person

Another factor is the origin of your organization, If English is not your main language and it is quite common for the people to make mistakes. HR Guy may just ignore it.

Next time take 1 minute time for reading your mails without hurry before hitting the send button. Best Wishes!!

Answer (score 1):

If you lose out on a job offer, it is unlikely that it will over a one-off typo in an email unless the typo is one of those typos that totally changes the meaning of your communication, in which case you owe the lucky recipient of your email a redo that includes an apology. And the more abject the apology, the better :)

Lacking an essential qualification or running into a candidate who is just better rounded than you or making the wrong birth choice and not being the business owner's child - that's far more likely to do you in.

Comment: As it happens, your phrase "lacking is an essential qualification" could use a little grammar love ;)

Comment: @jpatokal Thanks for catching it - my brain is very resistant to catching my own mistakes :)